# ListView not updating on new inserted items into ObservableCollection on UWP for Windows 10

Tags: sqlite, listview, win-universal-app, observablecollection, inotifypropertychanged

Im trying to understand how all is connected and I need some help.
So far I can do insert, update, delete into sqlite database but I cant make the UI show the changes from the database automatically without me to update the ItemsSource on the ListView whenever changes are made to the database. i.e.:

In my **App.xaml.cs**

```
public App()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.Suspending += OnSuspending;

            //Connection to the database and create the table if not there
            string path = Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "db.sqlite");
            SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(path);
            conn.CreateTable<CheckListItemModel>();
        }
```

Than in my **MainPage.xaml** i have a simple page with two buttons and the Listview

```
<Page
    x:Class="Personal_Checklist_2.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Personal_Checklist_2"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="100" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal" >
            <Button Content="Add Sample To Db" Click="Add_Sample_To_Db_Click" Margin="10,0,10,0" />
            <Button Content="Clear Tasks" Click="Clear_Tasks_Click" />
        </StackPanel>

        <ListView Name="lvListView" Grid.Row="1" >
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Id}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

In **MainPage.xaml.cs** code-behind I also keep as simple as I know just to add new row into the table and clear the table

```
using Personal_Checklist_2.DataModels;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using SQLite;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace Personal_Checklist_2
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        static string path = Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "db.sqlite");
        ObservableCollection<CheckListItemModel> Tasks = new ObservableCollection<CheckListItemModel>();

        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            using (var conn = new SQLiteConnection(path))
            {
                var query = conn.Table<CheckListItemModel>();
                Tasks = new ObservableCollection<CheckListItemModel>(query.ToList());

                lvTasksList.ItemsSource = Tasks.ToList(); //<<<--- If I dont do this, list is not updated
            }
        }

        private void Add_Sample_To_Db_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var Task = new CheckListItemModel()
            {
                taskTitle = "Sample Task"
            };

            using (var conn = new SQLiteConnection(path))
            {
                conn.Insert(Task);
                var query = conn.Table<CheckListItemModel>();
                Tasks = new ObservableCollection<CheckListItemModel>(query.ToList());
                lvTasksList.ItemsSource = Tasks.ToList(); //<<<--- If I dont do this, list is not updated
            }
        }

        private void Clear_Tasks_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            using (var conn = new SQLiteConnection(path))
            {
                conn.DeleteAll<CheckListItemModel>();
                var query = conn.Table<CheckListItemModel>();
                Tasks = new ObservableCollection<CheckListItemModel>(query.ToList());
                lvTasksList.ItemsSource = Tasks.ToList(); //<<<--- If I dont do this, list is not updated
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The database table model looks like this **CheckListItemModel.cs**

```
using SQLite;
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace Personal_Checklist_2.DataModels
{
    class CheckListItemModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        #region Private fields on DataModel
        private string _taskTitle;
        #endregion

        #region Public properties on DataModel
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int taskId { get; set; }

        public string taskTitle
        {
            get { return _taskTitle; }
            set { _taskTitle = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("taskTitle"); }
        }
        #endregion

        #region INotifyPropertyChanged implementation
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (null != handler)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

But it doesn't look right to me this way. Is there a way to achieve this without setting the listview.ItemsSource everytime some changes in db.sqlite and how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cast your ObservableCollection toList() thats why it doesnt update. Change it to:

`lvTasksList.ItemsSource = Tasks;`

And when you add an item you dont have to read again from db

```
private void Add_Sample_To_Db_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var Task = new CheckListItemModel()
        {
            taskTitle = "Sample Task"
        };

        using (var conn = new SQLiteConnection(path))
        {
            conn.Insert(Task);
        }
        Tasks.Add(Task);
    }
```

Comment: This solution was very simple, just dont know if this is going to work when I'm gonna update something i.e. will the list and db gets updated aswell. Im gonna try and let you know. thanks

Comment: As I can see you have implement INotifyPropertyChanged witch inform if a value inside an item have changed. I can see you have implement it correct. Also i would strongly recommend to make sure that the `conn.Insert(Task);` or `conn.Update(Task);` was succesfull. you can return a bool e.x. bool `result =conn.Insert(Task);`

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a new ObservableCollection every time, instead of binding to a single ObservableCollection and changing the items in it.

So, keep `Tasks` as a single ObservableCollection and update its content based on the DB query results.

Comment: Hey Igor, I get what you saying I just cant find a way how to update the current Tasks instead of setting it to new ObservableCollection<>. I mean do I need some changes in my model class?